# Modifying sort in Matlab to distinguish between inequalities and equalities

Tags: matlab

Consider a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `MxN`. I would like your help to construct an algorithm that identifies the rows of `A` that are characterised by the same ordering of elements from smallest to largest in a strict sense. 
However, I cannot use `sort` because `sort` does not distinguish between equalities and inequalities.

Let me explain better with an example

```
clear
A=[1 -2 -4; ...
   0 -3  5;
   1  1  2
   1  2  3
   3  3  4
   10 7  11];
```

Notice that:

```
%A(1,3)<A(1,2)<A(1,1)  
%A(2,2)<A(2,1)<A(2,3)  
%A(3,1)=A(3,2)<A(3,3)  
%A(4,1)<A(4,2)<A(4,3)  
%A(5,2)=A(5,1)<A(5,3)  %equivalent to A(5,1)=A(5,2)<A(5,3)
%A(6,2)<A(6,1)<A(6,3)
```

Notice also that: the ordering (in strict sense) of row 1 is different from the ordering of any other row, the ordering of row 2 is the same as the ordering of row 6, the ordering of row 3 is the same as the ordering of row 5, the ordering of row 4 is different from the ordering of any other row.

Hence, I want an algorithm delivering a vector `B` of dimension `6x1` characterised by

```
%B(2)=B(6) and ~= all other elements of B
%B(3)=B(5) and ~= all other elements of B
%B(1)~= all other elements of B
%B(4)~= all other elements of B
```

The actual numbers put in `B` can be totally arbitrary. For example, I would be happy to get

```
B=[3;...
  2;...
  1;...
  4;...
  1;...
  2];
```

Let me show you why `sort` does not work

```
[~,index] = sort(A,2);
[~,~,Bwrong]=unique(index, 'rows');
```

`sort` identifies rows 3,4,5 as having the same ordering because it does not distinguish between equalities and inequalities.

Let me conclude by saying that I would prefer not to use loops because in reality `A` is very large.

Comment: Is `A` always a set number of columns? i.e. there is a fixed number of possible combinations of sorting in a given row?

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I got your question: the number of columns of `A` is finite. Hence, when a row contains equal elements there is a finite number of ways to sort them. In the example above  `A(3,1)=A(3,2)<A(3,3)` could be also written as   `A(3,2)=A(3,1)<A(3,3)` and the algorithm should recognised that these two orderings are equivalent.

Comment: My point is that, in this case, you have 3 columns. So there are 3^(3-1)=9 different combinations of signs (`=`,`<` and `>`) between the columns. That's 3 signs to the power of (3-1) comparison operators. You could leverage this by just having a fast loop (over the 9 options) to see which index to assign (i.e. 1 to 9)

Comment: I see. How can I avoid looping over rows, though?

Comment: Nothing about what I just suggested included looping over rows, you would use standard vectorised logical comparisons of each operator for each of the 9 combinations, over all of the rows in a given column.

Comment: I think I got confused on counting all possibilities of ordering: suppose I have 3 numbers `a1,a2,a3`. Then I can order them in `13` ways: `a1=a2=a3`; `a1<a2<a3`; `a1=a2<a3`; `a1<a2=a3`; `a1<a3<a2`; `a1=a3<a2`; `a2<a1<a3`; `a2<a1=a3`; `a3<a1<a2`; `a3<a1=a2`; `a2<a3<a1`; `a2=a3<a1`; `a3<a2<a1`

Comment: Apologies if your suggestion is completely different from what I'm trying, my knowledge of matlab programming is not advanced.

Comment: Ah I didn't account for changing column orders... just implement this in a loop and come back if it actually is too slow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need also to use the first difference of sorted `A` to take into account strict ordering.

```
[s, idx] = sort(A,2);
d = diff(s,[],2) == 0;
[~,~,B] = unique([idx d],'rows');
```

Comment: Took me a while to get it. I was thinking of using `sign(diff(...))` to recognize the set of (in-)equality operators, so was confused by your combination of `diff` and `sort`. Good solution!

Answer (score 1):

You want to sort rows based on the set of (in-)equality relations between subsequent elements along each row. This set can be obtained as follows:

```
s = sign(diff(A,[],2));
```

The matrix `s` contains -1 for `>`, 0 for `==`, and 1 for `<`. The `unique` call proposed by OP will work on the matrix `s`:

```
[~,~,B] = unique(s,'rows');
```

This answer is very similar to [rahnema1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51658412/7328782), but I think slightly simpler and easier to understand. That solution uses `diff` only to find equality, leaving the other ordering relations to the result of `sort`. Here we use `sign` to convert any positive difference into a +1, and any negative difference into a -1. Thus we can skip the sorting.

It is possible to make it into a one liner:

```
[~,~,B] = unique(sign(diff(A,[],2)),'rows');
```